# inverter ordem do push

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js, array-push

Estou usando o push em uma requisição para colocar novo elemento em uma lista, mas notei que o push coloca o ultimo resultado lá embaixo. Quero inverter isso.

Estou usando o v-for para listar, mas acredito que o "conserto" será no push mesmo...segue o código:

```
   dados.retornodosite.push(response.data);
```

Como inverter a array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## UNSHIFT

Se quiser pode usar o método **unshift**. Se quiser saber mais leia [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift).

```js
var nomes = ["João", "Maria", "André", "Marcia"];
nomes.unshift("Luís","Adriano");

console.log(nomes);
```

Comment: deu certo!!! muito obrigado!!

Comment: @HoracioNeto Se a resposta solucionou o seu problema marque-a como correta para que futuros visitantes também aproveitem a solução.

Answer (score 1):

### `Splice`

Se o objeto for um array, o `push` vai inserir no final. Para inserir no começo você pode usar o [`splice`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

Exemplo:

```js
var final = 4;
var comeco = 1;

var arr = [2, 3];

arr.splice(0, 0, comeco);

console.log(arr);

arr.push(final);

console.log(arr);
```

Resultado:

```
// inicial
[2, 3] 

// depois do splice
[1, 2, 3]

// depois do push
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```